# Failed to Load Application Context error while running JUnit test case

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit

I am using JUnit for unit testin for web services(Springs).

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:WSexample/config/service/WSexample-service.xml‌"})
```

and the test file is located in `WSexample/test/find/controller` location

I am using above code to load an xml file. it is throwing Failed to load Application Context error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.j‌​ava:308) at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListene‌​r.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109) at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListene‌​r.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75) at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestCont‌​extManager.java:321)

Comment: Please include the actual error

Comment: Again, don't use comments to update the question. Update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the `SpringJunit4ClassRunner` and `ContextConfiguration` to load your context file.

Check out [this](http://lstierneyltd.com/blog/development/examples/unit-testing-spring-apps-with-runwithspringjunit4classrunner-class/) post.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:myContext.xml"})
```

Comment: i used this but its giving failed to load applicationcontext error
My file is not located in WEB-INF folder. it is in different folder and its name is "WSexample-service.xml"

Comment: It is hard to help without seeing the pertinent portion of your test and the path to the context file you with to load. The question is, did you put the appropriate file name AND path in `ContextConfiguration`?

Comment: @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:WSexample/config/service/WSexample-service.xml"})
 and the test file is located in WSexample/test/find/controller location

Comment: Don't put this as a comment, update your question so if someone else looks at it they will see the update.